# set cookies for my whole site is not working

Tags: plugins, cookies, site-url

I'm trying to set the cookie to my site to **hide a div on click action**. Description of the problem.

1. I wanna set the cookie for the whole site not for particular page. I'm setting the cookie `on click` the div by

> jquery-cookie.js

1. when I'm clicking the div on home page the div is invisible throughout the site. but if I'm trying to remove my div on other page it is not invisible throughout the site.
2. I've tried the following functions of the **wordpress codex**

`site_url()`
`get_site_url()`
`home_url()`
`get_option('home')`

by these methods I've named the **domain** but it is not working. I've also tried `/` for the domain name it is also not working.
these all are not working for me. please suggest me some other method to do that.

My plugin site consist of 4 pages

url as follows

```
site/wordpress/
site/wordpress/contact-us-2/
site/wordpress/sample-page/
site/wordpress/test-page/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in domain Name I've used this

```
$urlOfSite =  get_option('home');
$url = parse_url($urlOfSite, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

url path . This is working for me .